# Getting category by name returns old or wrong category ID

Tags: category, magento-1, collection, name

Currently encountered a problem with catalog/category_collection.

When I'm trying to get category id by it's name it returns wrong category ID.

Anyone else had this problem and know a fix? I tried reindexing data, clearing cache nothing helps.

```
$category = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')->addFieldToFilter('name', $name);
$cat = $category->getData();
$id = $cat[0][entity_id];
```

Anyone maybe know an alternative to this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that two categories can have the same name and your code does not take that into consideration.

Here's how I would attack this problem:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('name', $name);

$ids = $collection->getColumnValues('entity_id');
```

Thus, your `$ids` array will contain all the category id with the name you specified.